# Доступ к конкретной директории VPS - возможные уязвимости

Tags: linux, ftp, доступ

Добрый день!

Возник следующий вопрос: если предоставить человеку доступ к определенной директории VPS (например, к директории с файлами конкретного сайта), можно ли каким-то образом обезопасить себя от того, что он может получить доступ к другим директориям сервера (например, с помощью web shells)?

Answer (score 0):

Можно, если сайт будет работать от имени того же самого пользователя и если никто до этого не выставлял права 777 на какие-нибудь файлы. Все нормальные shared-хостинги так и работают.

Только вовремя ставьте обновления, потому что периодически находят новые уязвимости. Следите за новостями.

Comment: Можно преобрести тех поддержку если бизнес позволяет. В последнее время очень много уязвимостей находят, за всем не уследишь. Если все держится на одном человеке активируйте автообновления, но это все равно не гарантирует 100% защиту.